# Scraping URL using IE in the background - how to quit IE process?

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I have some code that loads up IE, scrapes a webpage and then closes IE.

I imagine (correct me if I'm wrong) that the code will take slightly longer to run as you can physically see IE open, and then close again once the info has been scraped.

The problem is when I want to hide IE and then run the code - I don't what I need to write at the end to close each of the IE processes down...once the info has been scraped.
See below:

```
Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
sURL = Cells(i, 10)
wb.Navigate sURL
wb.Visible = True
Do While wb.Busy = True Or wb.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
On Error Resume Next
      'scraping code here
wb.Quit
Set wb = Nothing
      'rest of the code here
```

So when wb.Visible = False, the wb.Quit doesn't work and you can still see IE running as a process (of course this uses a lot of memory and the code eventually crashes due to running out of memory).  What do I need to write to quit the process? Or is it a pointless exercise?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "each of the processes"?  You should only have one IE process. If there's multiple, that could be causing your problem because normally `.Quit` is all you need.

Comment: Couple other notes: `On Error Resume Next` should be avoided. You're telling VBA that you "don't care about errors" (instead of actually figuring out what's *causing* the errors). It's even more of a hinderance while troubleshooting a problem (like you are). You should remove that line and try running your code again.   Also, this is *mostly* cosmetic, but could cause some confusion: `wb` is generally used as an abbreviation for "Workbook", whereas `ie` is for "Internet Explorer"

Comment: Do you have a loop like `For i = ? to ?` when you refer to 'instances' and within this loop opening an `ie` object each time? If so, why won't you navigate to the next `sURL`?

Comment: @ashleedawg I feel a little embarrassed - for some reason now that I run the code with wb.Visible = False it doesn't load up a lot of IE processes. Perhaps I had a spelling mistake in the wb.Quit or an apostrophe in there by mistake...sorry - thank you for the input though!

Comment: @ashleedawg yes I agree it's not good practice - I wasn't aware what wb stood for so I will update to ie

Comment: @JvdV yes that is a much better idea. Yes I do have "next i" ...after "set wb - nothing".  Should I put this before "wb.quit" then?

Comment: You'll need to open the ie.application before the loop. Then navigate your links within the loop and only after the loop is finished you should quit the application.

Comment: Can you share an URL? It may be you don't need to open IE at all. And explain what you are after on the page. There is more than one way to "skin" a webpage so to speak.

Comment: If you don't mind me taking a few steps back: if all you want is scrape HTML, why would you be launching a web browser? Wouldn't XmlHttpRequest be much simpler, faster and more reliable?

Comment: @RuudHelderman That is what I am hoping OP will clarify though we may be dealing with a slow loading page.

Comment: What are you after from that page?

Comment: I am then using 'getElementById' to get the text that I want into a given cell - "transaction_chargeP0Y"

Comment: I tried with XMLHTTP but it seems that item is not loaded in time. So IE as above or Selenium Basic is also great. Interestingly, I can't even seen it rendered on the page though it is present in the HTML.

Comment: @QHarr that's a shame - try clicking 'Full 5 year detailed breakdown'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't issue an [XMLTTPRequest](http://ngislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) against that page for the element in question.

So here are two ways of getting that information. The second one shows you how to click your way through to it. The methods show how to wait, to close properly, as well as how to reference appropriately.

---

**Method 1: Internet Explorer**

```
Public Sub GetInfo2()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Const URL = "enter URL"
    Const WAIT_TIME_SECS As Long = 5

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim t As Date, transactionCharge As Object
        t = Timer
        With .document
            Do
                DoEvents
                On Error Resume Next
                Set transactionCharge = .getElementById("transaction_chargeP0Y")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > WAIT_TIME_SECS Then Exit Do
            Loop While transactionCharge Is Nothing
            If Not transactionCharge Is Nothing Then Debug.Print transactionCharge.innerText
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

In the above I have included a loop with timeout in case element is not immediately available.

---

**Method 2: Selenium Basic**

[Selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic) is a browser automation framework for VB.Net, VBA and VBScript

This shows you how to run a headless browser instance.

I have used the selenium explicit waits functionality to allow more time for element to be present on the page. Selenium also has implicit wait times.

The click events below open up the 2 different expandable show breakdown sections of interest.

The first is:

[image: first]

The associated HTML:

[image: HTML]

This line:

```
.FindElementByCSS("[data-reveal-id='detailed-breakdown']", Timeout:=7000).Click
```

uses a CSS selector to target the element by its styling on the page. It targets the attribute `data-reveal-id` with value `detailed-breakdown`. The `[]` indicates an [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute.asp).

The second click target is:

[image: target]

The HTML is:

[image: HTML]

We can see the parent `span` has an id we can target.

```
 .FindElementById("brkdownInvstToggler", Timeout:=7000).Click
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver '< You can use IEDriver for Internet Explorer
    Const URL = "enterURL"
    With d
        .AddArgument "--headless"
        .Start "Chrome" 
        .get URL
        .FindElementByCss("[data-reveal-id='detailed-breakdown']", Timeout:=7000).Click
        .FindElementById("brkdownInvstToggler").Click
         Debug.Print .FindElementById("transaction_chargeP0Y", Timeout:=7000).Text
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Selenium Type Library

---

**Side-note:**

If looping remember to set elements to `Nothing` before next loop round.

E.g.

```
Set transaction_charge = Nothing
```

Then process next URL.

Comment: What is the specific text you want?

Comment: and wow this looks like it will speed things up massively. Thank you. I am a little busy right now to test etc. but later this evening I will take a proper look

Comment: Looks like those particular values are slow to load :-(

Comment: Staring out? What does that mean please?

Comment: Sorry wasn't very clear - Do you mind replacing the web links with 'enter web-link here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178367/discussion-between-qharr-and-boswell).